# How to move a file into a cpanel folder

Tags: php

I have some of the other threads but still can't work out why I can't move a file into a folder with the following code? I am also wondering if there are any security issues such as people putting viruses on a file and will windows defender be good enough to prevent this?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $file = $_FILES['file'];
  $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $fileTmpName= $_FILES['file']['tpm_name'];
  $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
  $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
  $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

  $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
  $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

  $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

  if (!in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
      header("Location: upload.php?upload_form=typeerror");
        exit();
  } else {
      if ($fileError === 1) {
          header("Location: upload.php?upload_form=error");
        exit();
      } else {
         if ($fileSize > 500000) {
             header("Location: header2.php?upload_form=filesizeerror");
        exit();
         } else {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
             header("Location: header2.php?uploadform=success");
        exit();
         }
      }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKE2K.png)

Comment: wait.. you serve your site on a Windows Server? Have you enabled errors so you can actually see why it fails?

Comment: Can you show me html form

Comment: As you have fileType checks in - no one should be able to upload anything that isn't in that allowed array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have type mistake in tmp_name

change this line

```
$fileTmpName= $_FILES['file']['tpm_name'];
```

to

```
$fileTmpName= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: That was silly of me... So is there any security issues such as viruses by allowing people to upload files to my folder?

Comment: Can they hack the cpanel this way?

Comment: No, they can't easily. And check step by step while debugging your code

Comment: Can you help me with some other issues? I can't get any answers from my other threads about paypal donation button with ipn

Comment: I got this working now but now I have a 404 error

Comment: have you check the source code.